# Selecionar elementos que contenham um atributo "data" em particular

Tags: jquery, css, html5, seletores, html5-data

Na página existem diversos elementos com atributos `data`. Para evitar andar a adicionar classes de CSS ao elementos, tornado o código da página mais denso, gostaria de selecionar elementos pelo nome do atributo `data`.

#### Exemplo

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="text banana" data-my-target="John"></div>
<div id="myOther" class="text bread" data-my-target="Doe"></div>
<div id="myBother" class="text fun" data-my-girl="Jane"></div>
```

A ideia é aplicar determinada ação via jQuery aos elementos que contenham um atributo `data-my-target`.

## Pergunta

Como posso selecionar elementos pelo nome do atributo `data`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

```css
div[data-my-target]
```

Isso busca elementos que contenham esse atributo. Também é possível filtrar o atributo pelo valor. Por exemplo:

```css
div[data-my-target="John"]
```

O `=` casa elementos cujo atributo seja a string passada. Se quiser casar parcialmente o valor "John" (por exemplo, se o valor for "John Paul"), use `*=`:

```css
div[data-my-target*="John"]
```

Porém, acredito que a performance de usar uma classe seja melhor (não testei).

**Referência útil** (em inglês): [MDN CSS Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do ***bfavareto*** é a correcta.

Só para documentar mais 2 exemplos e diferenças de [**performance**](http://jsperf.com/data-my-target).

#### 1 :

```
$('div[data-my-target]');  // mais compatível com browsers antigos
```

#### 2 :

```
$('div').filter('[data-my-target]'); 
// ou:
arrayEmCache.filter('[data-my-target]'); // no caso de já haver uma array de elementos em cache
```

#### 3 :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-my-target]'); // mais rápida mas não compatível com IE<8
```

Answer (score 0):

Modelo mais atual:

```
var target = $("#suaDIV").data("my-target");
```

Comment: como posso selecionar o valor do atributo ?