# Como acessar um jquery sem id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sempre acessei um jquery usando o comando: `$('#id_1')`, porém sempre em um corpo html que possui `id`. Como faço para acessar um corpo html que não possui `id`, usando o atributo `data-uid` no meu caso abaixo?

```
<img data-uid="_b03bc8304532" ui-sref=".image({uidImage: 
&quot;_b03bc8304532&quot;})" width="450" height="450">
```

Comment: `$("[data-uid=\"_b03bc8304532\"]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o seletor de atributo:
[Resposta do stack overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1955/selecionar-elementos-que-contenham-um-atributo-data-em-particular)

Ficaria algo do tipo: `img[data-uid*="_b03bc8304532"]`

Tem mais referências nesse link: [Seletor de atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletor_de_atributos)

Answer (score 3):

Pode ser assim:

```
$('*[data-uid="_b03bc8304532"]');
```

Seleciona todos elementos com esse `data-uid`. Alterei para um span para demonstrar:

```js
$('*[data-uid="_b03bc8304532"]').html('texto alterado');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span data-uid="_b03bc8304532"></span>
```

Comment: Caso ele queira 1 pode usar o `.each()` após esse comando

Comment: No caso `each`, ele vai poder manipular todos os elementos que retornarem